# How to use date_trunc with variable as timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, date, syntax-error, amazon-redshift

I have following value in my database:

```
Wed Jun 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

In my Code I got something like this:

```
2016-06-23
```

I need to query for a date like the one in my code, and in postgreSQL i found date_trunc to "cut off" unnecessary information from the date. The [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_date_time.htm) shows following usage example:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 2001-02-16 20:00:00
```

So I thougt this should work:

```
redshift.query("SELECT stuff, ts , date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP 'ts') as 'date' 
    FROM ::table_name 
    WHERE date = :day",{table_name: name, day: day}, function(err, data){

>>>error: Redshift query Error: error: syntax error at or near "'date'"
```

But obviously this didn't work. It told me that I got a syntax error near the "day", I gues its the 'ts'. In all the examples I found, the timestamp was hardcoded, but that is not what I need. Any Ideas how to use it with a colum as timestamp instead of hardcode ?

Comment: `with t(x) as (select current_timestamp) select x, date_trunc('day', x), x::date from t;`

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally used a literal `'ts'` instead of referencing column `ts`, it seems. Moreover, you cannot have a string literal like `'date'` as column alias. It has to be an identifier.

So it should look like

```
date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP ts) as "date"
```

Maybe you mixed up string literals (quoted with `'`) and identifiers (quoted with `"`).

Comment: I also used it without the ' ' , this was just a desperate try :D